# Create JPQLQuery from a persistent class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

So for example, if I create a JPQLQuery for the User entity like this:

```
public class QUser extends EntityPathBase<User> {}

QUser qUser = QUser.User;
JPQLQuery query = new HibernateQuery(getSession()).from(qUser);
```

Is it possible to do the same if I only have the persistent class?

```
JPQLQuery query = createFromPersistentClass(User.class);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace

```
QUser qUser = QUser.user;
```

with

```
PathBuilder<User> qUser = new PathBuilder<>(User.class, "user");
```

or in a generic way

```
PathBuilder<?> qEntity = new Pathbuilder(clazz, "entity");
```

Replace "entity" with any variable name you want.

Comment: I have genericDAO parametrized with the persistentClass and ID. Without knowing anything this seems to work:

    PathBuilder<?> qEntity = new PathBuilder<>(persistentClass, persistentClass.getName());